# Inno Setup doesn't place Start menu items in proper group

Tags: installation, inno-setup, startmenu

I'm not sure what in the world I'm doing wrong.. I could swear I've set everything right, but it keeps putting the start menu item in the wrong place.

[image]

As you can see here it says its doing it right.

[image]

You can see all my files on github here..
https://github.com/N6REJ/Wamp-Safe-Start

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

My wild guess is that there is (or was) already a shortcut in

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Wamp Safe Start.lnk
```

(e.g. from your earlier attempts)

Or there's another shortcut pointing to the same binary.

Windows 10 removes all duplicate shortcuts from the Start menu and also heavily cache the menu.

*Anyway, note that it's against Windows 10 guidelines to put more than one shortcut per application to the Start Menu.*

For a similar question, see [URL Start menu entry missing on Windows 10 although installed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33026088/850848).

Comment: could it be from my installing uninstalling constantly during testing?  You mentioned caching... 
Wamp ( wampservermanager.exe ) is at   

    `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Wampserver64\wampservermanager.lnk`  

where my program would be 
    `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Wampserver64\Wamp Safe Start.lnk`
 which goes to wampsafestart.exe

Comment: Could be, try the installer on a fresh/different machine.